# How to acknowledge subscription for purchases.subscriptionsv2 with ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, payment, google-play-developer-api, acknowledgepurchase

Since May 2022, The new [Play Billing Library version 5](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/compatibility) allows your app to benefit from all the new subscription features.

> While `purchases.subscriptions:get` has been upgraded to `purchases.subscriptionsv2:get`, the rest of the developer subscription management functions remain unchanged for now in the `purchases.subscriptions` endpoint, so you can continue using `purchases.subscriptions:acknowledge`

We notice there are three values of [AcknowledgementState in `purchases.subscriptionsv2:get`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2#PausedStateContext)

> ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED Unspecified acknowledgement state.
> ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_STATE_PENDING   The subscription is not acknowledged yet.
> ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_STATE_ACKNOWLEDGED  The subscription is acknowledged.

How to acknowledge subscription for purchases.subscriptionsv2 with ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED value? It seems we have no idea whether to acknowledge it or not.

---

Originally, there are two values of [acknowledgementState for `purchases.subscriptions:get`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions)

> 0. Yet to be acknowledged 1. Acknowledged

Only When the value of acknowledgementState is 0, we do the acknowledge for this subscription.

Comment: I got the same problem, do you find the answer?

Comment: @Cositanto, currently, we do acknowledge when the AcknowledgementState is NOT ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_STATE_ACKNOWLEDGED.